# SubView of SceneView not always centered

Tags: autolayout

When adding a CoachingOverlay to a SceneView (in viewDidLoad), the overlay is sometimes not centered but appearing in the bottom right of the screen. Why does this happen? The overlay in the bottom right would be centered if the screen had double size, so is the size not set yet? Or may it be because i'm using ARKit in a custom react native module? Thanks

```
coachingOverlay.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
sceneView.addSubview(coachingOverlay)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  coachingOverlay.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sceneView.centerXAnchor),
  coachingOverlay.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sceneView.centerYAnchor),
  coachingOverlay.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sceneView.widthAnchor),
  coachingOverlay.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sceneView.heightAnchor)
])`
```

The same thing happens with a MBProgressHUD:

```
self.hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.sceneView, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding an additional view between the view/sceneview and the hud and coachingoverlay subviews:

```
let container = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.view.addSubview(container)
self.hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: container, animated: true)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  self.hud.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerXAnchor),
  self.hud.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerYAnchor),
  self.hud.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.widthAnchor),
  self.hud.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor)
])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this pls

```
yourSubView.center = CGPoint(x: yourView.frame.size.width  / 2,
                         y: yourView.frame.size.height / 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my case this did not help.